# outlier detection for subjective rating data which is not consistent among raters

Tags: statistical-significance, experiment-design, outliers

In my experiment, I invited 3 experts to evaluate dance performance of 20 subjects. So for each subject, he or she will get 3 scores given by expert individually. For most of the subjects, 3 experts' evaluation are consistent. However, for several subjects, the score given by experts have big difference. For example, for subject 01, expert A gives score 70, expert B give score 50, expert C gives score 30. But for other subjects, the differences are very small. I already used intra-class correlation coefficient to check the consistency among 3 experts' evaluation, it turned out okay, which means the overall evaluation among 3 expert are consistent. Therefore, I want to know is there some statistic methods to detect the subjects whose score is not consistent among 3 experts? I want to remove these subjects as outliers.Thank you in advance.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an answer, but I do have an advice, and it's the same advice my mother used to give me

> The first thing you do, with any sort of data, is you plot it.

In lieu of real data I've had to do with simulations. Hope it fits somewhat.

```
set.seed(1)

ee <- sort(rbeta(20, 2, 3))
ea <- ee + (rbeta(20, 2, 3) - 0.5)*0.1
eb <- ee + (rbeta(20, 3, 3) - 0.1)*0.1
ec <- ee + (rbeta(20, 4, 2) - 0.1)*0.1

e <- cbind(ea, eb, ec)
e <- e + sample(c(rep(0, 20), 0.2, 0.3), length(e), replace=TRUE)
e <- floor(e / max(e) * 100)

par(mar=c(2, 2, 0.5, 0.5))
matplot(e, type="l", lty=1, lwd=2)
legend("topleft", legend=LETTERS[1:3], col=1:3, lwd=2)
```

[image]

As you can see, the three judges are in broad agreement, but there are some idiosyncrasies. For example:

- Judge A gives on average lower scores than the other two.
- There are a few obvious instances where one of the judges has had a very different impression from the other two. Like with subject 4, 5 and 11, where judge C gives by far the highest grades.
- Less obvious is the case with subject 15. Although the score given by judge A isn't all that high compared to the other two's, it is significant in that it's the only case where judge A gives the highest score of all.

So which of these are outliers? Which of these should be removed? Maybe 6, maybe 12, maybe half, maybe none? It all depends.
Maybe outliers shouldn't be removed completely, but rather given less weight in further analysis? Maybe the distributions should be scaled or transformed in another way? It all depends.

Comment: I just attached one figure to show the evaluation from experts. But I still hope there is a statistical way to remove some outliers. Thank you.

Comment: @XiaoqunYu: That depends on what you mean by 'statistical'. There is no magical solution where you don't have to make a judgement call and an algorithm will take the decisions for you. You'll have decide for yourself what constitute an outlier and what does not, and what to do with them. Maybe you specify a model and say that anything that deviates sufficiently from the parameters of that model is an outlier? In any case you'll have to specify the model and argue for why your decisions make sense.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to quantify the consistency in ratings among the raters, on a per-subject basis, is to compute the standard deviation (or range, or mean absolute deviation from the median) of the three ratings.

Whether it makes sense to remove these inconsistently rated subjects as outliers isn't clear; I would have to know more about your analysis and your analytic goal. But I doubt it does.

Comment: I developed one algorithm to atomically evaluate subject's dance performance. So experts' evaluation would be my golden reference to check the accuracy of my algorithm. I found if judges give very different scores, which is also far away from the result of my algorithm. Therefore, I want to use some statistical way to remove these subjects.

Comment: @XiaoqunYu I see, so cases where experts disagree is where it's too hard to say what the right answer is and hence to evaluate your algorithm. That makes sense. However, since you have only 20 subjects, I would advise against removing any. More than two would be pushing it, since you'd then be throwing away more than 10% of the data. So perhaps remove the single most variable subject, or the top two.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I just edited my question, I attached one figure to show the evaluation result of 3 experts for you to easily check the result. But I still hope there is a statistical way to help me remove these "outlier" instead of manually to delete.

Comment: @XiaoqunYu I'm not sure what you mean by a "statistical way" as opposed to a "manual" way. It's not as if you need an automated method to handle hundreds of datasets of several thousand subjects each. You have one dataset of 20 subjects. Is my suggestion insufficiently statistical somehow?